# How to add paragraph while states changing in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I am quite new in React. I am trying to find a way for write something i.e. "actions loading .." while states implemented.

The problem is that the states added, then changes performed to the program. What I would like is while adding states, do something like `<p>actions loading ..</p>`

Here is my code:

```
{states.length > 0 && (
  <div>
       Actions loading ..
  </div>
)}
```

The program here is, added the states, then added the paragraph.

Please see a screenshot of the states that added to my app.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary operator to show `Actions Loading` when the length of the state is zero.

```
{states.length === 0 ? 0  (
  <div>
       Actions loading ..
  </div>
) : (
  <p></p>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help if you add a bit more context for this component, but if you have something like this

```
const MyComponent = props => {
  const [states, setStates] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    myRequest().then(setStates);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {states.length > 0 && (
        <div>
         Actions loading ..
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

and you want to either show the states or a message, you could change the render to

```
    <div>
      {states.length > 0 ? (
        <dix>
         {states.map(state => <MyState/>)}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
         Actions loading ..
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank Antastasiia for your comment, I will try that.